# CasperJS cannot find element even though I can CTRL-F it in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, casperjs

```
'use strict';

var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true, logLevel: 'debug'});
var element = '/html/body/div[7]/nav/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form';

casper.start('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/', function () {
    if(this.exists(element)) this.echo('Found it!');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Ok, so this code snippet is as simple as it can be. I spin up a new CasperJS instance, GET `http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/`, echo if an element is found, then exit. Now, what I cannot seem to grasp is why in the world the above code doesn't find that element (XPath) but if I load up Chrome Developer Tools, I can CTRL-F it. Same results when I substitute CSS Path for XPath. Can anyone please enlighten me? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the XPath utility of CasperJS for that since `element` is an XPath expression and not a CSS selector.

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/', function () {
    if(this.exists(x(element))) this.echo('Found it!');
});
```

Comment: I was literally testing this just now and all is well. Thank you for the quick answer.